# Workflow 4 Activity in designer: dependency error on a specific assembly version?

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have the following VS 2010 solution setup:

The application project executed references an project *Libraries.Workflows* which contains only workflows / .xaml files. This Libraries.Workflows project references a *Libraries.Workflows.Activities* project which basically contains all custom wf activities.

The Libraries.Workflows.Activities assembly uses a type defined in *Libraries.CustomTypes*. This type has a base class defined in *Libraries.SomethingElse*.

Now the problem is that the solution & projects compile & work perfectly fine - however, when opening a workflow of *Libaries.Workflows* which uses one of the activities in *Libraries.WorkFlows.Activities* that have an *In/OutArgument* in the WF Designer within Visual studio, an error is shown stating the following:

Error 3 Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "requirements".
Reference required to assembly 'Libraries.SomethingElse, Version=1.0.3965.31164, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the base class 'Libraries.SomethingElse.Baseclass'. Add one to your project.

Now the Version number 'expected' increments with each build... as if the workflow somehow/somewhere had a 'strong' (but wrong) reference.

Has anyone come across something like this before and knows what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause (and workaround): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/c2b2ef64-7cba-4eb0-a767-9ff83dafa5dd

Apparently this should have been fixed in beta2 of WF4 but is still there in the RTM version.

Comment: You can also just add the namespace of the missing type to the "Imports" tab. This resolves the issue for me